# Hosting WCF Web Serveic on Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, windows-server-2003, wcf-rest

Getting the following err...

> Server Error in '/' Application. IIS
>   specified authentication schemes
>   'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication,
>   Anonymous', but the binding only
>   supports specification of exactly one
>   authentication scheme. Valid
>   authentication schemes are Digest,
>   Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous.
>   Change the IIS settings so that only a
>   single authentication scheme is used.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: IIS
>   specified authentication schemes
>   'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication,
>   Anonymous', but the binding only
>   supports specification of exactly one
>   authentication scheme. Valid
>   authentication schemes are Digest,
>   Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous.
>   Change the IIS settings so that only a
>   single authentication scheme is used.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: IIS
>   specified authentication schemes
>   'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication,
>   Anonymous', but the binding only
>   supports specification of exactly one
>   authentication scheme. Valid
>   authentication schemes are Digest,
>   Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous.
>   Change the IIS settings so that only a
>   single authentication scheme is used.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.SetBindingCredentialBasedOnHostedEnvironment(ServiceEndpoint
>   serviceEndpoint, AuthenticationSchemes
>   supportedSchemes) +446264
>   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.AddAutomaticWebHttpBindingEndpoints(ServiceHost
>   host, IDictionary`2
>   implementedContracts, String
>   multipleContractsErrorMessage) +709
>   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.OnOpening()
>   +203    Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost2.OnOpening()
>   in
>   e:\bt\3781\Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web\Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web\WebServiceHost2.cs:69
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +229
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +121
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +479
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The
>   service '/Service.svc' cannot be
>   activated due to an exception during
>   compilation.  The exception message
>   is: IIS specified authentication
>   schemes
>   'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication,
>   Anonymous', but the binding only
>   supports specification of exactly one
>   authentication scheme. Valid
>   authentication schemes are Digest,
>   Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous.
>   Change the IIS settings so that only a
>   single authentication scheme is
>   used..]
>   System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +11599786
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +194
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication
>   context, Boolean flowContext) +176
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +278
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +75
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.3615;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618

Comment: As i the same published service is working fine in my local PC in Win 7 but when I try to do so. on Windows Server 2003 it gives me the above err msg.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error above, you have [IIS authentication configured](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/36ea667e-c578-43b5-87fa-a2f174efb27a.mspx?mfr=true) on your Windows 2003 machine to allow two different types of authentication (integrated & anonymous). Change it to one type of authentication - the one that matches your WCF configuration. I'm guessing you only want anonymous (and not integrated) enabled in the IIS configuration, but that's your design choice..